# Отключение Beaglebone Bkack при загрузке с sd карты

Tags: linux, arm, embedded

При установке нескольких пакетов, по небрежности удалил каталог /lib. Решил создать загрузочную sd карту. Скачал образ со свежей ОС с официального сайта (моя версия была 2022 года, новая 2023). Плата Beaglebone Black C. Процесс загрузки с sd запускается, наблюдаю за ним через консоль порта serial, однако на определенном этапе светодиоды платы гаснут, в консоль выводятся нечитаемые символы. Плата ни на что не реагирует. При повторном включении ситуация повторяется. Флешка 16 Гб.

Comment: попробовать другую sd карту, попробовать версию 2022 года, показать читаемый вывод что идёт перед не читаемым

Comment: может скорость порта поменялась

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле установка ОС происходила корректно. В момент завершения установки плата отключается, возможно для того чтобы можно было извлечь sd карту. При повторном включении плата запускается с новой ОС, но этого в консоли serial можно не заметить. Увидеть результат успешной установки ранее я не мог, поскольку не было кабеля micro HDMI. Уж не знаю, будет ли это кому нибудь полезно...